# When give number ranging from 1 to N. Find sum of left and right indices.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Considering a set. Now given numbers from 1 to N and Q queries. In each query a number p is added to the set and we have to output sum of left and right indices of all good ranges. 
Good Range - largest range that contains only one element for Set.

Ex: 
Let N =10 .

Query 1 - 2 is added to set. Then Good Range = 11 [1,10].

Query 2 - 5 is added to set . Good Range = (1+4) + (3+10)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you please edit your post and explain better your problem? As it is, I find it hard to understand what are the left and right indexes and what are you summing.

Comment: Left and right indexes are the position of numbers in given range( here 1 to N). Summming the indexes (means position number).